# iOS 8 App sound wont play

Tags: ios, audio

While using the code

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"spoken" ofType:@"mp3"]];
AVAudioPlayer *click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
[click play];
```

I get no errors, but the sound will not play in my application. My volume is on max, also.

I'm also importing

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: why do you say that you get no errors if you pass a `nil` NSError into `initWithContentsOfURL`? also, the line initialising `musicFile` is not complete. are you sure the file is there?

Comment: @sergio : Its no just a comment, your comment should be the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up an ivar for your `AVAduioPlayer`:

```
@interface yourPlayerClass
{
    AVAudioPlayer *click;
}
```

Then:

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"spoken" ofType:@"mp3"]];
click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
[click play];
```

Hope this helps.